# How to change 'Base Url' (<base href="" />) in an HTML string through RegEx-PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I am working on a project where i need to parse and manipulate HTML. I have a requirement of replacing 'Base Url' in the HTML string. I am trying to use RegEx for the purpose. I have tried multiple patterns, but no luck. Below is my current code -

```
<?php
$html = '<html><head><base href="/" /></head><body></body></html>';
$base = 'https://SOME_URL/';

$output = preg_replace('/<base href="(.+)">/', $base, $html);

print $output;
```

Current Output -

`$html = '<html><head><base href="/" /></head><body></body></html>';`

Expected Output -

`$html = '<html><head><base href="https://SOME_URL/" /></head><body></body></html>';`

Comment: Its not recommended to use regex to parse HTML. Take a look at DOMDocument to do this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex - `<base href="(.+)">`, is not matching because the part after `"(.+)"` is wrong. Look at the source string - `<base href="/" />`, see that  ? and the `/`? and *then* the `>`.

This is just one of the many reasons parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea. That element is perfectly valid even without that space and maybe even without that `/`.

However, if you're 100% positive that the position of this `base` element won't get too complex (e.g lot of nesting, new lines between the attributes etc). You may be able to get by with just - `/<base[ ]*?href=".+"/i`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVW1Ee/3)

In PHP, to get your expected output, you'd do-

```php
$base = 'https://SOME_URL/';

$output = preg_replace('/(<base[ ]*?href=").+(")/', "$1$base$2", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
(?<=<base\s)href="(.*?)"
```

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GKxaIZ/3)

```js
  $html = '<html><head><base href="/" /></head><body></body></html>';
  $base = 'https://SOME_URL/';
  res=$html.replace(/(?<=base\s)href="([^"]*)"/,`"${$base}"`)
  console.log(res)
```

Comment: `[<base]` matches a single character in the list `<, b, a, s, e`. `href+` matches `hrefffffffffff`, there're no needs to escape equal sign, your regex doesn't work if there is another `/>` in the line, see https://regex101.com/r/GKxaIZ/2

Comment: £Toto I have fixed it do you think it needs anymore adjustments ?

Comment: Why are you using a lookbehind, it's use less here? And why a character class  `[<ba]`?  How do you replace with the requiered string?

Comment: OP want to change base urls !!

Comment: Well, but, how do you change it? Where is the code? And you didn't answer my previous questions: Why are you using a lookbehind? Why a character class `[<ba]`?

Comment: do you know of a method to match a link in base tag without using something like a  lookbehind ?

Comment: Look at the other answer!

Comment: I have looked at the other answer I just don't see any reason to match <base> as well, maybe you can enlighten me into why you think it should be matched, since php is not supported here to run the code I have made a snippet in `js` replacing the base url do you think the same can't be achieved in php?

Comment: and personally I think DOM parser is the best solution to this question

Comment: That's better, you've completly changed the regex. I agree with you for parser, that's why I've closed the question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks , they were constructive :)